# MVC5 how do I render/create/change button colours using a method/condition from the controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to dynamically render a web page's button by using a condition. I was thinking along the lines of having something like this in the controller:

```
public bool checkUser(){
    if (User.Identity.Name == "Bob"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in the View I want to do something like:

```
@if (checkUser){
    <type = "button".....></>// create a red button
}else{
    <type = "button".....></>// create a blue button
}
```

But I'm not exactly sure how to pass the boolean result of a method into the view. I hope I was able to explain my issue properly, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the `ViewBag`. Assign the value inside the action and access it in the view with same key

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ViewBag`.

Assign the value inside the action

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    bool checkUser;
    if (User.Identity.Name == "Bob"){
        checkUser = true;
    }else{
        checkUser = false;
    }
    ViewBag.checkUser = checkUser;
    return View();
}
```

and access it in the view with same key

```
@if ((bool)ViewBag.checkUser){
    <type = "button".....></>// create a red button
}else{
    <type = "button".....></>// create a blue button
}
```